# Celery equivalent of a JoinableQueue

Tags: python, queue, celery, python-multiprocessing, gevent

What would be Celery's equivalent of a [`multiprocessing.JoinableQueue`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.JoinableQueue) (or [`gevent.queue.JoinableQueue`](http://www.gevent.org/gevent.queue.html#gevent.queue.JoinableQueue))?

The functionality I'm looking for is the ability to `.join()` a Celery task queue from a publisher, waiting for the all tasks in the queue to be done.

Waiting for an initial `AsyncResult` or `GroupResult` isn't going to be sufficient, as the queue dynamically fills up by the workers themselves.

Comment: Can you pls clarify, why `group(*tasks) > apply > join` is not sufficient?
How workers affect your group result? Why you cant handle `.join` results?

Comment: @Slam Because that would only wait for the initial group of tasks to be done. The workers don't affect the group results, they add more tasks to the queue. My intention is to wait for all the tasks in the queue to be done (similar to the way I can `join()` a `JoinableQueue` which would wait for `task_done()` to be called on every single task in the queue).
I could probably achieve this by creating an additional shared counter and a pub/sub in Redis, but I was wondering if there's a cleaner and more reliable method using just Celery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might not be perfect, but this is what I came up with eventually.

It's basically a `JoinableQueue` wrapper on top of an existing Celery queue, based on a shared Redis counter and a list listener. It requires the queue name to be the same as it's routing key (due to internal implementation details of the `before_task_publish` and `task_postrun` signals).

**joinableceleryqueue.py**:

```
from celery.signals import before_task_publish, task_postrun
from redis import Redis
import settings

memdb = Redis.from_url(settings.REDIS_URL)

class JoinableCeleryQueue(object):
    def __init__(self, queue):
        self.queue = queue
        self.register_queue_hooks()

    def begin(self):
        memdb.set(self.count_prop, 0)

    @property
    def count_prop(self):
        return "jqueue:%s:count" % self.queue

    @property
    def finished_prop(self):
        return "jqueue:%s:finished" % self.queue

    def task_add(self, routing_key, **kw):
        if routing_key != self.queue:
            return

        memdb.incr(self.count_prop)

    def task_done(self, task, **kw):
        if task.queue != self.queue:
            return

        memdb.decr(self.count_prop)
        if memdb.get(self.count_prop) == "0":
            memdb.rpush(self.finished_prop, 1)

    def register_queue_hooks(self):
        before_task_publish.connect(self.task_add)
        task_postrun.connect(self.task_done)

    def join(self):
        memdb.brpop(self.finished_prop)
```

I've chosen to use `BRPOP` instead of a pub/sub as I only need one listener listening to the "all task finished" event (the publisher).

Using a `JoinableCeleryQueue` is pretty simple - `begin()` before adding any tasks to the queue, add tasks using regular Celery API, `.join()` to wait for all the tasks to be done.